# Testing website in nightwatch without browser

Tags: testing, nightwatch.js

is any chance to test website by url and do not open browser so any info output will be in the command line?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PhantomJS](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Running-tests-in-PhantomJS) if you just don't want to run a browser but it sounds like may just want to see the output, have you tried running with the [--verbose](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/running-tests/runner-options.md) flag?

Comment: yes, exactly ! I want to see output. No I haven't but now i testing Phantomjs with casper.js and it "He does the work"